# .NET website with References in GAC - How to deploy?

Tags: asp.net

Quick question which I thought would be easily answered.

I have a .net website, which has references to dlls in the GAC.

When I build this and deploy to another server (in production) which doesn't have the same DLL references in the GAC, how can i get the dlls across?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a manual process where you copy across you're website, you'll have to seperately copy your GAC dll and install that on your production server.

You can do this using GacUtil.exe (found in the Visual Studio/SDK/bin folder) or you can use the Admin Tools.NET Framework 2.0 Configuration MMC Snapin under Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the GAC!!!  The gac is bad.  Any other application can end up changing a DLL in there and if you're not referencing the exact version, your application will change.

Comment: Ummm... no; the GAC specifically avoids that with versioning via strong names.

Comment: Hmmm...really?  Doesn't the developer have to remember to take the time to do that or does it force you?  plus, when you checkout code or deploy to a new environment, you aren't guaranteed to have the DLLs with you in the project.  You have to remember to put them in the GAC or hope they are already installed.  Even so called "System" DLLs like Entity Framework and MVC microsoft is now making easily referencable in your project using nuget.  I'd recommend the nuget way over the gac every time.

Comment: Yes. You have to make sure they are installed. That's exactly what the question was about... his project *is* using a GAC assembly.